# jquery isn't loading on start up for IE

Tags: jquery, startup, doctype

So everything loads on start up good in chrome and firefox, but in IE it doesn't work on start up and I have to click in a link to go to another page and then go back in order for the script to start working.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bigimage').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({
         "width": "110%",
         "left": "0px",
         "top": "0px"
      }, 200,'swing');
   }).mouseout(function(){ 
      $(this).stop().animate({
         "width": "100%",
         "left":"15px",
         "top":"15px"
      }, 200,'swing');
   });
});
```

html

```
<ul class="getbig"> 
   <li>
      <a href="*"><img class="bigimage" src="pic.png" title="mytitle"></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="*"> <img class="bigimage" src="pic2.png" title="mytitle2"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.getbig{ position:relative; left: 50px; top: 0px; width:200px; height:78px;  }

.bigimage{ position:relative; width:100%; left:15px; top:15px}
```

So I am wondering if it has to do with doctype in IE.

Comment: Are you getting exception? If yes, what is that?

Comment: Working fine, add the correct script source **Working demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/HM5sm/ `:)`

Comment: Sorry I'm not anywhere savy in jquery yet.  By script source you mean the location of the script on my computer then yea it's correct seeing it works in chrome and firefox...just not in IE. And what is meant by exception?  I see no errors anywhere. Thats odd that it's working in that jsfiddle on start up.  Would this have anything to do with IE nagging about not letting scripts unless you press the accept button?

Answer (score 0):

> Would this have anything to do with IE nagging about not letting
>   scripts run unless you press the accept button?

Yes - does it work if you 'allow blocked content'?

If so, there are two solutions:

- load your page through a web server instead of as a local file (IE restricts the page from running scripts only for local files)
- use [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28VS.85%29.aspx) (MOTW). But this is a non-standard workaround, and introduces other issues (IE will then [disable any links to other file types](http://ss.johncardinal.com/motw.htm))